# GCP Logs - How to filter out Stored Procedures or SQL

Tags: logging, stored-procedures, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to retrieve a Stored Procedure from the logs in GCP.
I can see lots of entries in the log just wondering what parameter should I set in the Query Builder to just filter out Stored Procedures that I have run in the past?

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
..
...
..
END
```

I have tried the below filters:

resource.type="bigquery_project"
"bigquery.jobs.create"

Answer (score 1):

While there are [audit log entries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/BigQueryAuditMetadata) related to creation/modification/deletion of routines (the underlying API abstraction used to expose stored procedures and UDFs), there is not a structured response in the audit log that indicates which stored procedures were called as part of an individual query.

Additionally, it the [jobs-related INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) views do not expose referenced routines either (but referenced_tables is exposed).

You could considering scanning SQL text, for instances of `CALL` statements, but such an approach may not be sufficient for your needs.  It may also be worth [raising a support request or public issue](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-support) related to this.